# django doesn't load initial fixtures while syncdb

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

I've got a django project with following structure:

```
/djninja # project dir
  /djninja # main app dir
  /bands # app dir
  /fans # app dir
  /lyrics # app dir
```

I've created a `initial_data.yaml` file to make `syncdb` load fixtures (I prefer YAML format). According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/initial-data/), I shall put it in any app `fixtures` subdirectory. And so I did, I had:

```
/djninja
  /djninja
  /bands
    /fixtures
      - initial_data.yaml
  /fans
  /lyrics
```

But syncdb was omitting the file. Then I moved it into main project directory:

```
/djninja
  /djninja
    /fixtures
      - initial_data.yaml
  /bands
  /fans
  /lyrics
```

And still it is being omitted. I'd like to load fixtures within `syncdb` command What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you installed yaml so that python will recognized that as fixtures?

Comment: I use json syntax (initial_data.json) and it works ok... perhaps .yaml is not the right extension? Have you tried other format?

Comment: @catherine: I was missing python-yaml package. I've installed it, but still python doesn't load fixtures.

Comment: @catherine pyyaml is called python-yaml in Debian. So that may well have been it.

Comment: Try this one for test: `python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial_data.yaml`

Comment: `$ python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial_data.yaml`
`Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)`

Comment: python manage.py loaddata initial_data.yaml

Answer (score 7):

Apparently Django looks for fixtures in apps specified in `INSTALLED_APPS` that have a `models.py` in them.

So if your app is missing one, create an empty `models.py` and Django won't skip looking for fixtures in that app.

Answer (score 1):

`initial_data.yaml` should be picked up as long as:

- you have pyyaml installed
- it's located in `fixtures` directory of one of your apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` (in `settings.py`)

So, given you have pyyaml it's probably the latter. Please make sure your `fixtures` directory is inside one of the apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` and you should be up and running.

In case of this layout:

```
/djninja
  /djninja
  /bands
    /fixtures
      - initial_data.yaml
  /fans
  /lyrics
```

adding `bands` to `INSTALLED_APPS` should do the trick, given `bands` is a valid package and is on `PYTHONPATH`.

If you'd like Django to look for fixtures in some other directory, you can follow the advice given in ["Where Django finds fixture files" subsection of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#where-django-finds-fixture-files) and use the `FIXTURE_DIRS` setting, making it a list of extra directories to look in.